# Promise await different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Why in the flowing code in the first arrow function we get promise resolve value `some data` as a string, but in second we get `Promise { 'some data' }` ?

```js
const resolveAfter2Seconds = ()=> {
         return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve("some data");
            }, 2000);}
        );
    };

    (async()=>{
        let prom=await resolveAfter2Seconds()
        console.log(prom)
    })();



    (async()=>{
        let prom=resolveAfter2Seconds()
        await prom
        console.log(prom)
    })();
```

Comment: you aren't getting the result from the promise on the lefthand side of your 2nd `await`

Comment: Because you are doing different things? `await` does not return the promise object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `await prom` doesn't modify what the variable `prom` refers to, it just waits for the promise that it refers to to settle. `prom` still refers to a promise when you log it. If you want to update `prom` with the result from the promise, you need to do that explicitly:

```
prom = await prom;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just run `resolveAfter2Seconds()`, that function in itself returns a `Promise`. So `prom = resolveAfter2Seconds();` will always have the promise as the value of the variable. When writing `await` in front of `resolveAfter2Seconds()`, you tell JS to wait for the promise that is returned by the function to be resolved before the variable is set, then the returned value of the promise is passed to the variable